# Is there some way to put all of NW.js's "help-files" in a subdir?

Tags: nwjs

Once my NW.js project is finished and packaged, I end up with a nice `Whatever.zip`. The user opens that file archive, finding a dir called `Whatever`, and extracts this to their desktop. Then they open the dir.

Inside, they find a massive number of files (`d3dcompiler_47.dll`, `nw_elf.dll`, `resources.pak`, etc.) and subdirs (`locales`, etc.), and somewhere inside there, my `Whatever.exe` and `README.txt`.

This looks so messy.

I wish that, instead, the user opens the dir and finds only this:

```
Whatever.exe
README.txt
<DIR> NWJs
```

That would be so clean and nice. The user would immediately see the EXE they are supposed to run, and the README.txt that I made. If they are morbidly curious, they can go into the `NWJs` dir and find all the files that are 100% unrelated to my application.

I know that there is that third-party "Enigma" thing, which turns everything into a single file. That's not what I'm looking for.

Yes, I know that I can make an installer for people to use, and I also do that. This is unrelated to that as well.

Is it possible? I never could understand why they made this design choice. But there is no obvious way (IMO) to accomplish this, since the EXE file (renamed and icon-changed NW.exe) expects all those weird little (and big) files to be in the same dir. I sure hope this can be configured without having to "build a custom NW.js" (which is sadly not going to happen).

Answer (score 1):

This design choice was made by Chromium, NW.js just inherited it. Chromium was always intended for non-technical audiences. Meaning that it would only be distributed by an installer that would place these files in the `Program Files` folder, or somewhere similar, then create shortcuts to the executable on the desktop or start menu.

If you want to do that, there are tools like NSIS, WinRAR's SFX, or Inno Setup. There are also automated build tools (like NW.js Builder Phoenix), though none well maintained, that can simplify the creation of an installer.

Alternatively, if you have more technical users, you can just do the "Unzip/Double-Click" approach, like you're currently doing. There is no way around having the supporting files being in the same directory as the executable.